# in Polymer not able to push elements in Array type polymer property

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am using Polymer 1 in my project . I am using array type polymer property in this property i want to hold or store elements in _extractTimeSeriesData callback .below is the piece of code which i am using . this callback is executing whenever i am getting response from  Rest API  . 
Here i want to store elements in _series property as (self._series.push({ x: point[0], y0: (1 - (point[1])) * 100 });

but while executing code i am getting error as  **Uncaught TypeError: self._series.push is not a function**

```
Polymer({
      is: 'test-view',

      behaviors: [GlobalsBehaviour],

      properties: {

           timeSeriesData: {
            type: Object,
            observer: '_extractTimeSeriesData'
          },
       _series: {
          type :Array,
          value :[]
        },

  _extractTimeSeriesData: function (raw) {

          if (raw !== null) {
            tagsArray = raw.tags;
            for (var i = 0; i < tagsArray.length; i++) {
              if (this.ltuTag == tagsArray[i].name) {
                var datapoints = raw.tags[i].results[0].values;
                var self = this;
                datapoints.forEach(function (point) {
                  self._series.push({ x: point[0], y0: (1 - (point[1])) * 100 });
                });
                console.log("chart data value is", _series);
              }
            }
          }
        },
```

i tried to use first 
this._series.push({ x: point[0], y0: (1 - (point[1])) * 100 }); but it didnt work then also i tried to refer this using varible as self as above code but this is not working .

Can anyone please tell me how can i store elements in Array Type  polymer property.

Comment: `self._series.value.push({ ... })`?

Comment: Thanks @Pointy yes it worked for me but i didn't understand the exact reason why it worked with this (self._series.value)  Can you please explain me ...

Comment: Well the value of `self._series` is an object with two properties: "type" and "value". You have to directly manipulate the "value" property to change the value.

Answer (score 4):

You have to call `self.push('_series', dataStuff)`. Polymer 1 does wrap the default manipulation methods for you. So to change your properties you have to call `this.push('propName', value)` or `this.set('propName', value)` or `this.splice('propName', value)` etc.